# Why Does Teamviewer run in WINE at boot?

Tags: 14.04, wine, teamviewer

Why does TeamViewer 10 run in WINE at boot, but after running `sudo pkill TeamViewer.exe` and open the program through Unity, it runs regular?

This Picture shows TV10 running in Wine at boot:
[image: Wine at boot]

This picture shows running the command to kill TV10:
[image: Killing TV10]

This image shows reopening TV10:
[image: Reopening TV10]

Here we see TV10 running without Wine:
[image: TV10 running without wine]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native version of TeamViewer for Ubuntu (or even Linux in general). The installer is in a nice, Ubuntu'ish deb installer, but it brings its own installation of Wine with it, which shouldn't interfere with anything else on your system. It's nothing to worry about, and it works quite well.