# Is wineserver a default (program/process) on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, wine, process

I saw in my Ubuntu 14.04 installation that there is a process called `wineserver`.

Is that a default process/program when you install Ubuntu? I have another machine running the same OS (14.04) and don't have this process running.

PS.: I don't have wine (run win apps) installed in both machines.

Comment: You answered your own question, "I have another machine running the same O.S 14.04 and dont have this process running." so as you can see wine / wineserver is not installed or running by default.

Comment: Yes. But is there possible that when install other program it install wineserver? why is that process there? for what? maybe some one install it manually? how do I know how and when it was installed?

Comment: Did you install Wine on the system?

Comment: No, never. only use it to access others hosts from this machine ip(allowed on remote servers).  what this service is doing? any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wineserver` is a component of wine. It shouldn't be present in a default clean Ubuntu installation. Someone either manually installed it or it was installed as a dependency of another package.

Please try the following:

1. Where is `wineserver`?

   Use `which` to find out:

   ```
   $ which wineserver 
   /usr/bin/wineserver
   ```

   `winserver`'s full path is `/usr/bin/wineserver`.
2. What package "owns" that file?

   Use `dpkg -S`:

   ```
   $ dpkg -S /usr/bin/wineserver
   winehq-devel: /usr/bin/wineserver
   ```

   `/usr/bin/wineserver` is there because it is part of package `winehq-devel`.
3. Why is that package installed? (You'll need `aptitude` for this, or you can also use `apt-cache --installed rdepends <package>`)

   Run `aptitude why`:

   ```
   $ aptitude why winehq-devel
   i   playonlinux  Depends  wine | wine-development
   i   winehq-devel Provides wine
   ```

   `winehq-devel` was manually installed (the line starts with `i A` for automatically installed packages). It's also a dependency of package `playonlinux`, so if I uninstall `winehq-devel` I have to uninstall `playonlinux`, too.
4. If you don't need it, remove it.

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge winehq-devel
   ```
5. When was it installed?

   `dpkg` maintains a log in the files `/var/log/dpkg.log*`

   ```
   $ grep "install winehq-devel" /var/log/dpkg.log*
   /var/log/dpkg.log.1:2016-04-04 14:01:31 install winehq-devel:amd64 <none> 1.9.7~ubuntu16.04.1
   ```

   Of course, replace `winehq-devel` with the actual name of the wine package installed in your system. As you can see, `winehq-devel` was installed on 2016-04-04 14:01:31.

   There's also the `apt` logs located at `/var/log/apt/history.log*`. I found this in file `/var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz`:

   ```
   Start-Date: 2016-04-04  14:01:00
   Requested-By: carvalho (1000)
   Install: ..., winehq-devel:amd64 (1.9.7~ubuntu16.04.1), ...
   ```

   No surprise, I intentionally installed `winehq-devel`.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for help.
1.) when I run:  '#sudo which wineserver' , it return nothing.
1.1) '#ps -A | grep wine' , show pid number and wineserver
1.2) '#ls - l /usr/bin/ | grep wine' , try find wineserver path like you said and return nothing 
1.3) so I run your command but different because I dont have any wineserver on /usr/bin so I run '# dpkg -S wineserver' , and it return my TEAMVIEWER wineserver path  '# /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/wine/wineserver'

I think I solve my problem, teamviewer use wineserver or whatever, right?

Comment: @rafaelphp I just found [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/594854/65926) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/125153/65926). Yes, Teamviewer runs on Wine. There's nothing wrong with your system.